# Extract Twitter short url from tweets stored in database - mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

I have tweets stored in database. Some tweets contains twitter short links like `https://t.co/'+10_digit_alpha_numb`. I want to extract these links from `tweet_text` column as using `substring` and `REGEXP` or similar concept

One thing is common in these tweets that the link is coming in the last. I am able to find tweets with the links using `REGEXP` but not able to get these links as `substring`

My code to selecting tweets with links presented in the last

```
SELECT tweet_text, -- substring_index(<extract_link>) 
  FROM user_tweets
 WHERE tweet_content REGEXP 'https://t.co/[a-zA-z0-9]{10}$'
```

Comment: the `$` at the end is the end of line anchor it matches only if short link is at the end of `tweet_content`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul yes I wants only those tweets having links in the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pattern implies a fix length of 23 characters a quick solution

```
select substring(tweet_text, -23)
...
```

from [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html)

> MySQL's support for regular expressions is rather limited

...

> If you want more regular expression power in your database, you can consider using LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG.

PREG_CAPTURE should be the needed function.

Comment: Wow ! Why I couldn't think like that.